# Replacing words and symbols in Multiple columns based on condition

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe,df with 3 columns:**FirstCol**,**SecndCol**                    **ThirdCol**. I intend to match the words in the Firstcolumn and if the word ends with **up** which is the last word in **FirstCol**, replace the value:**0226e0ad** in the **SecndCol** with **''0226e0af''** and replace the last symbol **<*>*** with **''up''** in the ThirdCol. 
Otherwise,if the last word ends with **down**,leave the value of the second column and replace the last symbol **<*>** with **''down''** in the ThirdCol.

NOTE: There are other messages that end with Up and Down too that I don't intend to change like:

```
 %PKT_INTTT-LITT-3-UPDOWN : gate txE0/4/1/4, changed state to Down,8bea0c5d,%PKT_INTTT-LITT-3-UPDOWN gate <*> changed state to <*>
 PKT_INTTT-LITT-3-UPDOWN : gate txEE0/2/1/7, changed state to Up, 8bea0c5d,%PKT_INTTT-LITT-3-UPDOWN gate <*> changed state to <*>
```

But only the messages in the FirstCol should be changed

```
FirstCol                                                             
%TTT_IND-LITEALL-5-UPDOWN : Sig col on gate txE1/1/1/1 , changed state to Up          
%TTT_IND-LITEALL-5-UPDOWN : Sig col on gate txE1/16/1/4, changed state to Down



SecndCol                    ThirdCol
0226e0ad         %TTT_IND-LITEALL-5-UPDOWN : Sig col on gate <*> changed state to <*>   
0226e0ad         %TTT_IND-LITEALL-5-UPDOWN : Sig col on gate  <*> changed state to <*>
```

This will now give:

```
FirstCol                                                             
%TTT_IND-LITEALL-5-UPDOWN : Sig col on gate txE1/1/1/1 , changed state to Up         
%TTT_IND-LITEALL-5-UPDOWN : Sig col on gate txE1/16/1/4, changed state to Down



  SecndCol                    ThirdCol
  0226e0af         %TTT_IND-LITEALL-5-UPDOWN : Sig col on gate <*> changed state to Up   
  0226e0ad         %TTT_IND-LITEALL-5-UPDOWN : Sig col on gate  <*> changed state to Down
```

Any ideas on how to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to create mask with [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and replace values using [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html).

```
mask1 = df['FirstCol'].str.contains(r'Up$|Up.', regex=True)
mask2 = df['FirstCol'].str.contains(r'Down$|Down.', regex=True)

cond = df['FirstCol'].str.contains(r'-LITT-',regex=True)

df.loc[mask1 & ~cond, 'SecndCol'] = '0226e0af'
df.loc[mask1 & ~cond, 'ThirdCol'] = df.loc[mask1, 'ThirdCol'].str.replace(r'(\<\*\>)$', 'Up')

df.loc[mask2 & ~cond, 'ThirdCol'] = df.loc[mask2, 'ThirdCol'].str.replace(r'(\<\*\>)$', 'Down')
```

Comment: Thanks  for this @Abhi! However, the FirstCol has other strings that have Up and Down that I don't want to change unless it matches that particular message depicted above in the FirstCol

Comment: @Bode That's the reason I have used a `regex` to match the word only at the end. You can verify it. It will work. It will only look for `Up` or `Down` at the end of `first col`

Comment: Okay but it changed some other messages which has Up and Down as its last word too

Comment: @Bode Can you update the above question by adding 1 or 2 rows which is causing the issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182238/discussion-between-abhi-and-bode).